# mySQL if X > Y Do not save information

Tags: jquery

I have a function that stores returned information from a API.

I already have a if statement that tells the user the accuracy of a returned call was too low. But how do I do the same for my mysql statement?

```
if(tag.uid == 0) s += "I got something, but the data wasn't clear. Sorry.";
     if(tag.confidence < 80) {
      s += "<li>User identification accuracy was too low, please try again</li>";
    }
     else if(tag.uid) { s += "<li> User:" + uid + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Accuracy:" + tag.confidence + "%" + "</li>";
     if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Timestamp:" + log_time + "</li>";
    }


    } 
    if(photo.tags.length) {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "mysql/save.php?uid=" + tag.uid + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day + "&hours=" + hours + "&min=" + min + "&suffix=" + suffix + "&accuracy=" + tag.confidence,  true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

I would think its pretty much the same as the previous statement but do not know how to write the error statement as I dont want to alert the user of the error, just not save any information till the accuracy rate improves.

Comment: Please sort out the indentation of your code, it's hard to read and it looks to me like you're missing a `{` near the top. Please also explain what you are referring to as "the previous statement".

Comment: has this anything to do with java, php, jquery and mysql? look plain javascript to me

Comment: If this is jQuery, why are you using `window.XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Dave I didnt post all the code but `{` is at the top. Dancrumb, I searched around for a way to save the returned information and found that and it works the way I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was actually really simple.

```
if(photo.tags.length) {
      var tag = photo.tags[0].uids[0];
      s += "<p>";
     //$('#result') .html ('Welcome Back:' + photo.uid + ',' + 'Confidence:' + photo.confidence);
     if(tag.uid == 0) s += "I got something, but the data wasn't clear. Sorry.";
     if(tag.confidence < 80) 
      {
      s += "<li>User identification accuracy was too low, please try again</li>";
      }
     else if(tag.uid) { 
       s += "<li> User:" + uid + "</li>";
       if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Accuracy:" + tag.confidence + "%" + "</li>";
       if(tag.uid) s += "<li> Timestamp:" + log_time + "</li>";
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "mysql/save.php?uid=" + tag.uid + "&month=" + month + "&day=" + day + "&hours=" + hours + "&min=" + min + "&suffix=" + suffix + "&accuracy=" + tag.confidence,  true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
```